# ajaxSubmit in combination with SimpleModal doesn't fire succes delegate

Tags: jquery, simplemodal, jquery-forms-plugin

With the following code I'm trying to execute some actions after the ajaxSubmit, but the success delegate is never fired. The ajaxSubmit code reaches the asp.net controller who succesfully handles the request with an JSON result. The model form contains an button who executes the AjaxSubmitAndClose.

```
function ShowModal(rendercontainerid, modalcontainerid, url) {
        if (url == '')
            return;
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            $(rendercontainerid).html(data);
            $(rendercontainerid).modal({
                close: false,
                containerId: modalcontainerid
            });
        });
    }

    function AjaxSubmitAndClose(formid) {
        var options = { 
                        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
                        success: showResponse,
                        dataType: 'json'
                        };


        $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
    }

    function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) 
    { 
        $('#formSub').html('We really appreciate your feedback!');
        var queryString = $.param(formData); 
        alert('About to submit: \n\n' + queryString); 
        return true; 
    }

    function showResponse(responseText, statusText) 
    {
        alert('status: ' + statusText + '\n\nresponseText: \n' + responseText + 
            '\n\nThe output div should have already been updated with the responseText.'); 
    }
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you please leave only what's relevant to the issue. Also, I don't get what var form = $(formid); $(form).validate(); does. Shouldn't it be form.validate() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating this strange behavior I found an open [bug](https://github.com/malsup/form/issues#issue/64).
Then I did a shot in the open and I removed dataType from the Options 
object and surprisingly everything was working again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET, I believe you need to use the `appendTo:'form'` option for the modal:

```
$(rendercontainerid).modal({
    appendTo: 'form',
    close: false,
    containerId: modalcontainerid,
    // snip
});
```

Comment: is this also valid if you use ASP.NET MVC? Or only with the ASP.NET Forms

Comment: After an test I could say this isn't valid on ASP.NET MVC